# How can I merge elements of an array in a loop in JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays

If an array contains the same number in adjacent positions, they are merged into a single number like in the example input and output below with double that value.

```
int[] test = {2,0,2,4,0,0,4};
Tile.alter(test)
true
test
{ 4, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } //(the two 2’s merged, and the two 4’s merged)
int[] test = {2,0,4,2,0,0,4};
Tile.alter(test)
true
test
{ 2, 4, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0 } //(nothing merged – the 2’s are not adjacent, nor are the 4’s)
```

I tried this and its not working:

```
int curr=size[i];
if(size.length<=0)
int prev = size[0];
size[0]=size[0]*size[1];
for(int j = 0;j<size.length;j++)
size[j]=prev*size[j+1];
prev=curr;
size[size.length-1]=prev *size[size.length-1];
```

Comment: you have to use two for loop 1 for next val and another for compair.

Comment: why do you need  answer sorted {4, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } and what you have done to achieve this..

Comment: He is trying to do something like merging happens in 1024 or 2048 games.

Comment: @therealboyi: what do you expect in this case: `{2,0,4,2,0,0,2}`? `{2, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}` or `{2,4,4,0,0,0,0}`?

Comment: @STaefi, I expect {2,4,4,0,0,0,0}

Comment: @therealboyi: Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

So I don't really understand what you are trying to do but here is my guess:

You start with an array

```
int[] a = {/*Some numbers*/};
```

You then shift the array's values to the left until it has the sum of a block.

```
for (int i = 0, index = 0, current = a[0]; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] == 0) {
        continue;
    } else if (current == 0) {
        current = a[i];
    }
    if (a[i] == current) {
        a[index] += current;
    } else {
        index++;
        current = a[i];
        a[index] = current;
    }
    if (i != index) {
        a[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

If all of my assumptions are correct this may work (I haven't tested it). If it is required that a new array is used, then just clone a before starting.

Comment: Okay, the method above by @Clone Talk worked, but the 0th position in the output array keeps on multiplying itself by 2 before even merging with any other similar original number. Anyway to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved in many ways, but for a clean and understandable code I suggest the following approach:

1. First shift the intermediary zeros to the end, so you can have the non-zero element adjacent to each other. For example:

   `[2, 0, 2, 4, 0, 0, 4] => [2, 2, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0]`
2. Do the possible merges, two by two, because you don't need a chain merge:

   `[2, 2, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0] => [4, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0]`
3. Again shift the intermediary zeros to the end:

   `[4, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0] => [4, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

Since each of the above stages can be done using one iterate over the array then the whole algorithm is from `O(n)`.

You can find the algorithm implementation as follow:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MergeAdjacent {
    
    private static int[] mergeLeft(int[] original) {
        int[] zeroShiftedForMerge = shiftZerosToRight(original);
        //
        for (int i = 0; i < zeroShiftedForMerge.length-1; i++) {
            if(zeroShiftedForMerge[i] == 0)
                break;
            if(zeroShiftedForMerge[i] == zeroShiftedForMerge[i+1]) {                
                zeroShiftedForMerge[i] += zeroShiftedForMerge[i+1];
                zeroShiftedForMerge[i+1] = 0;   
                i++;
            }           
        }
        //
        return shiftZerosToRight(zeroShiftedForMerge);
    }
    
    private static int[] shiftZerosToRight(int[] original) {
        int[] zeroShifted = new int[original.length];
        int ind = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < original.length ; i++) {
            if(original[i] != 0) {
                zeroShifted[ind++] = original[i]; 
            }
        }
        return zeroShifted;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] test1 = {2,0,2,4,0,0,4};
        int[] test2 = {2,0,4,2,0,0,4};
        int[] test3 = {2,0,0,2,0,0,4};
        int[] test4 = {2,0,4,2,0,0,2};
        int[] test5 = {4,0,4,4,2,0,4};
        //
        int[] merged1 = mergeLeft(test1);
        int[] merged2 = mergeLeft(test2);
        int[] merged3 = mergeLeft(test3);
        int[] merged4 = mergeLeft(test4);
        int[] merged5 = mergeLeft(test5);
        //
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test1) +" => "+ Arrays.toString(merged1));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test2) +" => "+ Arrays.toString(merged2));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test3) +" => "+ Arrays.toString(merged3));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test4) +" => "+ Arrays.toString(merged4));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test5) +" => "+ Arrays.toString(merged5));
    }
}
```

Run the program above to see the inputs and outputs:

> [2, 0, 2, 4, 0, 0, 4] => [4, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>
> [2, 0, 4, 2, 0, 0, 4] => [2, 4, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0]
>
> [2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 4] => [4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>
> [2, 0, 4, 2, 0, 0, 2] => [2, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>
> [4, 0, 4, 4, 2, 0, 4] => [8, 4, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0]

Hope this would be helpful.